# ContextMenu and ontouchListener android

Tags: android, contextmenu, ontouchlistener

I'm developing an application which in an specific Activity, I have a button I want to drag and drop (for this, I use onTouchListener) but otherwise, I want that the button has a context menu (press the button for a long time)... But it seems that there is a conflict between the two options, because if I put the two options, then only works the onTouchListener...

Is there any option to use the two options?

Thanks!

Comment: think about it for 5 minutes.....drag and drop and also long press...don't you think its bad idea?

Comment: @Paresh Mayani well, yes... but It is not my decision.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for me:

```
    final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context,new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Longpress detected");
        }
    });

    button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {          
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
              switch (event.getAction()) {
                     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                           //Whatever you do
                           return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                     case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                           //Whatever you do
                           return false;
                     default:
                           break;
               }
               return false;
       }
    });
```